# var/session is huge then invalid key on login

Tags: magento-1.9

I've noticed every so often the inability to logon to my admin page as it'll throw an invalid form key, everytime this happens i have to delete all sessions in the var folder, refresh the page then im in.

This folder is absolutely massive.

Is there a way to limit the amount of sessions that can be stored to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into http://php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

There are two PHP settings to add a probability to run the session garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Increase session expired time value in backend setting.